# Adding Connections to the delegate of a ListView

Tags: listview, delegates, qml, qt5

I have a ListView declared in a qml file( made by someone else ). This ListView already has a delegate, also declared in that file.

In a separate file, I'm trying to use that component and to add behaviour(Connections and Binding) to each row in that list, without modifying the first file ( layout ).

Is that possible ? 
Basically, I'm trying to (completely)separate logic from layout.

**EDIT 1 - code**

**main.qml:**

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MyList {
        id : list
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Bill Smith"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "John Brown"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Sam Wise"
            }
        }
    }    
    //here I want to add behaviour to each item in the list
}
```

**MyList.qml**

```
Item {
    property alias list: myList
    property alias model: myList.model

    ListView {
        id : myList
        delegate : MyDelegate{}
        height : 500
    }

}
```

**MyDelegate.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id : myDelegate

    property alias mouseArea : mouseArea
    property alias label : label.text

    width : 100
    height : 100
    color : "#C0FFEE"

    MouseArea {
        id : mouseArea
    }
    Text {
        id : label
    }
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Uh... can you show some code? It sounds a bit dodgy, to be honest. Usually you'd "override" their delegate with your own, and use normal property bindings rather than the `Bindings` and `Connections` types.

Comment: What do you mean by Connections and Binding (Signal/Slot concept?) and delegate (StyledItemdelegate?)?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r: He's using QML, so QtQuick's ListView delegates and QML bindings

Comment: @Mitch I've added some code. The designer will choose the delegate for the list. We only know that this delegate has some alias properties.

Comment: I think this also depends on how the rows are instantiated in a listView.